# How to implement Split Screen Multitasking on iPad using Third party apps?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xamarin, split-screen-multitasking

I tried to implement the Multitasking feature Apple provided using AIR application, but I seem to miss something.

I did the following as apple recommended:

1. Compiled the app with iOS9 SDK.
2. All orientation implemented.
3. Storyboard added.

Still I do not see the vertical bar that divides the two app's for multitasking.

Let me know if you implemented this successfully in any third party apps?

Answer (score 6):

All 3 listed steps are correct. Please also make sure `Requires Full Screen` is set to `NO`. It works perfectly for me.

Please let me know if you (or anyone else) still have trouble with Split View support.

Answer (score 3):

What iPad are you using to test your app? Not all iPads support this behavior. This table shows which iPads support Slide Over, Picture in Picture and Split View:

[image: Multitasking]

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html) from Apple for more information.

By the way how did you manage to use launch screen storyboard with Adobe AIR application?

Comment: I posted this question when i was working for Adobe AIR app in Adobe. The feature is alredy out :)

Answer (score 2):

Split screen wasn't working for me because even though I had a Storyboard, I wasn't using it. Make sure your `Launch Screen File` is set, and your `Launch Images Source` is blank.

[image: Launch Screen File]

---

Check off `Portrait`, `Upside Down`, `Landscape Left`, and `Landscape Right` under Deployment Info. Also make sure that `Requires full screen` is not checked off.

[image: Deployment Info]

---

Finally you should double check that your Info.plist is correct. `UIRequiresFullScreen` should be NO. `Supported interface orientations` and `Supported interface orientations (iPad)` should have all 4 orientations.

[image]